# How to send large amount of data from node.js app to a python file?

Tags: node.js, json, object, spawn

I have a json object containing 2(or more) nested objects , and in each object their are 18 key value pairs, basically the json object is an object which stores article and each nested object contains this type of information.

```
{
createdAt: date,
lastUpdated: date,
content: of 250 words,
...
.
.
.
.
.
.

and many more fields
}
```

Now i want to send this object to a python file for some machine learning application, and i have done it using spawn module , i send this data by this command:

```
const childPython = spawn('python', ['hello.py',JSON.stringify(posts)])
```

But it shows this error:

```
(node:21728) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: spawn ENAMETOOLONG
    at ChildProcess.spawn (internal/child_process.js:403:11)
    at spawn (child_process.js:553:9)
    at Object.showObj.getSimilarArticles (D:\done\VSCode\learners backend v2\controllers\showPageController.js:92:27)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
    at async D:\done\VSCode\learners backend v2\routes\posts.js:1519:3
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:21728) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:21728) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Now my question is is it because of large size , if yes is there any other solution possible to communicate the data?
If no, what am i doing wrong, how can i correct it?

Comment: I would probably just write it to a file. Use "fs" from Node.js to write the JSON to a file. Then you can just read that with whatever Python module is used to read files.

Comment: Can you add the whole code? How large data are we taking about mbs or gbs? It seems that the issue is with the function you are calling it from.

Comment: Actually i used python-shell module from npm , and it works now. Thanks for your input @LeeMorgan your idea is quite decent.

Comment: @ApoorvaChikara The data is in kbs actually , there must be a problem elsewhere.